# MS Office 2013 64-bit limitations

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office

I am trying to find out what are the disadvantages of the 64-bit Office. There are several items which are listed on Microsoft page, but some points are not clear for me. If someone knows, please explain it for me.

1. `32-bit ActiveX controls, both third-party and Microsoft-supplied, are not compatible with the 64-bit version of Office 2010`

Can you give me an example of active-x controls loaded to the standard Office with no third party add-ins? Do any standard processes involve active-x, which won't work in 64 bit edition?

2. `These applications also block a 64-bit Office 2013 installation: •Compatibility Pack for the 2007 Office system`

Does it mean, that compatibility pack is not available in 64-bit Office and 2007 files will not be viewable in Office 2013?

3. `WLL (Word Add-in libraries) WLL files are available for 32-bit Office 2013 and aren’t supported in 64-bit Office 2013.`

Does that mean that NO add-ins will work in Word 2013 64-bit, or only those, which have .wll extension?

Answer (score 3):

1. The standard Office 2013 64-bit install contains no (incompatible ActiveX) add-ons.
2. This is saying that if you have programs in that list installed already (ie: the *Compatibility Pack for the 2007 Office system*) then they can/will block your install of Office 64-bit.
3. WLL's are a specific type of add-on, which Office 64-bit does not support.

Comment: I don't see the point is installing Office 64-bit. Is your one application planning on using more than 4GB? I can't see this happening unless you're running Microsoft Access with huge queries that belong on SQL Server. If not, 32-bit may provide better compatibility (e.g. WLL) than 64-bit.

Comment: @sunk818 I must say this does happen. Our accounting and sales and marketing departments run into this problem a lot when using excel. We did have to upgrade them to 64bit to fix the problem.